# Crystal Reports - Hide page header and details section on last page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to hide page header and details section if there are no more records to show. Actually if there are such number of records that can be fit on first page then second page is showing page header and empty details section. How to avoid from this?

[image]

Comment: Is there additional blank spaces in the detail section? Or can you provide some screenshot of the design view?

Comment: I think, there is some issue in the design. The detail section should show detail data and the header/footer is a summary on top of it. I could see detail data in the report footer also. Also in the section wizard, try setting the keep-together option.

Comment: I have set the keep-together option but no success. And also I need to follow the same design :(

Comment: I have some how remove the details section problem. Now what I am facing is just the header. Header comes on the page where there is no more record but only footer needs to be there. How to remove header though?

Comment: Would you mark this question closed? There should be a **close** link right below the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use group header instead of page header? In group options, you can set 'repeat group header on each page' - this is IMHO correct way to display column headers.

Comment: How can I use group header? As I am new to crystal reports and I am not able to find group header

Comment: Go to Section Expert. You should be able to locate it easily there.

Comment: In older Crystal, it is located in Group expert, not in Section expert. This makes me sick sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;
else
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource =<ur data source>;
```

Comment: Can you please give an explanation along with your answer?